# construct two dimensional array in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

let  us consider following  equation

```
x(t)=sum(a(i)*sin(2*pi*f(i)*t+b(i)*cos(2*pi*f(i)*t))
```

where  i=1,2,......m  and  frequencies  `f=[f1,f2,.....fm]`   and `t=[t1,t2,....tn]`

i want to create  matrix by `sin(2*pi*f(i)*t)`  and `cos(2*pi*f(i)*t)`,clearly it would be matrix with dimension `NX2*m`,i have tried following code

```
function [amplitudes]=determine_amplitudes(y,f,t,n,m);

X=zeros(n,2*m);
for i=1:n
     for k=1:m
      if mod(k,2)==1 
          X(i,k)=sin(2*pi*f(k)*t(i));
      else
           X(i,k)=cos(2*pi*f(k)*t(i);
      end

     end
end
end
```

i used  mod operator to determine that if k is odd index,then there should be written sin value,else cosine value,but  problem is that i am not sure  that given matrix would be with dimension NX2*m,so how to  create such matrix so that not exceed index of bounds of frequency  array ,recall that frequency array is following  `f=[f1,f2,..fm]`,so my problem simple is how to apply  m  frequency at 2*m position,thanks  for help

UPDATE:

let  say m=3, and frequencies  `f=[12.5 13.6 21.7]`

then we have following matrix ,also assume

```
 n=4 t=[0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04]

 sin(2*pi*f(1)*t(1))  cos(2*pi*f(1)* t(1)) sin(2*pi*f(2)*t(1)) cos(2*pi*f(2)*t(1)) sin(2*pi*f(3)*t(1)) cos(2*pi*f(3)*t(1))
```

Comment: I think the final matix would be of size `nXm` because with the `if` conditional it's just selecting one of sin or cos terms, isn't that right?

Comment: no no,select sin or cosine yes,but ok i will update my question to clarify it

Comment: i have updated please see and thanks for reply

Comment: sorry  there must be  2*m components,there is no space,it should  sin(f(1) cos(f(1)) sin(f(2) cos(f(2)) and so on

Comment: f has three values,how can it have f(4)?

Comment: i have update,in columns only t(1),t(2)..t(n) is changing

Comment: OK, so the final matrix would have number of rows = n and number of cols = 2*m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No loop version**

```
[f1,t1] = meshgrid(f',t');

p1 = sin(bsxfun(@times,f1,2*pi*t')); %%// Create sin copy '
p2 = cos(bsxfun(@times,f1,2*pi*t')); %%// Create cos copy '

d1 = [p1;p2];
final_matrix = reshape(d1,size(p1,1),[]);
```

**Naive loop version**

```
final_matrx2 = zeros(n,2*m);
for k1=1:n
    for k2=1:2*m
        if rem(k2,2)==1 
            final_matrx2(k1,k2) = sin(2*pi*f(ceil(k2/2))*t(k1));
        else
            final_matrx2(k1,k2) = cos(2*pi*f(ceil(k2/2))*t(k1));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: please if it possible using loops?it would be more readily for me

Comment: no i have not tested  this code,just need to  have code like i have posted